# Field name changing, layer not saving

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers

At some point recently, when I create a new shapefile layer, the field names are being changed, and changes to the layers are not being saved. For instance, I will create a new polygon layer and add a couple fields upon creation. When I begin editing the layer and open the attribute table, the fields that I created are not there, and there is only one column called Actions, with Duplicate Feature and Digitize.

Some fields will be renamed with East Asian logograms. When saving the layer, I receive the attached message. Has anyone seen this behavior? I am considering a full reinstall, but wanted to check with others first.

I have multiple versions of QGIS installed (3.16 LTR, 3.20.4), and the same behavior exists everywhere.

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you forgetting to press "Add to fields list" when you are creating the layer?

Comment: shapefiles are quite particular about what you can call fields - what name are you trying to use?

Comment: I am "adding to field list" when creating. And the behavior is happening after the shapefile is created and I add fields when viewing the attribute table.

Comment: I always use the same field names- id, description, name, area, etc. Nothing fancy.

Comment: If you save after you add any fields, perhaps even stopping editing, then begin your editing and finish and save that, (prior to any other edits to the fields_, does that work?  If you make sure to put a unique id in for each feature you finish, does that work?

Comment: Nothing worked, including a reinstall of Q. I assumed it was some corruption in GDAL, GRASS, etc. I blitzed everything, started from scratch, and it is all good now.  Unfortunately I need to reinstall all my plugins, preferences, connections, etc. But at least I'm back in business. thanks-